# Unable to define a function in Jquery: "Uncaught ReferenceError: function1 is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
<textarea class="t1" onchange="function1('1','2','3')"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var function1 = function(p1, p2, p3) {
            alert('p1:' + p1 + ' p2:' + p2 + ' p3:' + p3);
        };
    });
</script>
```

However when I change the text of the textarea, nothing happens.

I get this error on the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: function1 is not defined

[**Live fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GgGSs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery :

```
<textarea class="t1"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.t1').on('change', function(){
            function1('1','2','3');
        });
        var function1 = function(p1, p2, p3) {
            alert('p1:' + p1 + ' p2:' + p2 + ' p3:' + p3);
        };
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U4sx7/

That makes me learn that the event `change` on a textarea is like `blur` for jQuery… Not sure, that's what you want in the end.

**EDIT after comment**

```
<textarea class="t1" data-pam1="1" data-pam2="2" data-pam3="3"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var function1 = function(p1, p2, p3) {
                alert('p1:' + p1 + ' p2:' + p2 + ' p3:' + p3);
        };
        $('.t1').on('change', function(){
           var param1 = $(this).data('pam1'),
               param2 = $(this).data('pam2'),
               param3 = $(this).data('pam3');
           function1(param1,param2,param3);
         });
     });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U4sx7/1/

Comment: I cannot do this, because I generate the textarea programically, so I don't know the parameters '1','2', and '3'. I have something like `<textarea class=\"t1\" onchange=\"function1('"+ x.Pam1 + "','" + x.Pam2 + "','" + x.Pam3 + "')\"></textarea>`

Comment: @enb081 and that's why you must be precise with your question. You don't need jQuery at all in that context or use it the smart way. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var function1 = function(p1, p2, p3) {
            alert('p1:' + p1 + ' p2:' + p2 + ' p3:' + p3);
        };
 </script>

 <textarea class="t1" onchange="function1('1','2','3')"></textarea>
```

Nothing first you need to define(initialize) the function and then you can call it....and dont define it under

```
$(function(){..HERE..})
```

then it comes under **GLOBAL scope**

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the position where your function is being defined (in fiddle, check the second dropdown near jQuery selection box)
2. Move the function definition outside of `domReady` declaration.

---

Currently, your function is parsed like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
var function1 = function (p1, p2, p3) {
    alert('p1:' + p1 + ' p2:' + p2 + ' p3:' + p3);
};
});
```

You need it inside the `head` tag instead. Chose `no wrap - in <head>` option from dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your function1 is only in the scope of the anonymous function passed to jQuery.

As you're using jQuery, why not use it fully? Attach a `.change()` handler to `.t1` -

```
$(function () {
  $(".t1").change(function(){
    alert("Do your thing here");
  });
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GgGSs/1/)